# Evaluating clustering/partitioning quality

Tags: graphs, partitions, clustering

I'm wondering what are the most common/recognized methods to assess the quality of a clustering.
That is because I have developed a tool that can cluster/partition a network (in this case, a public transport network represented by a GTFS feed) in several different manners (graph partitioning, hierarchical clustering, etc ...) and my **'real' metric is almost impossible to get**.
In brief, the 'real' metric would be the speed-up obtained using a cluster-based searched against the non cluster-based search. This depends on too many factors (input distribution, implementation of the search algorithms, architecture, etc ....).

I have developed a small function that can evaluate the quality of a clustering using the ratio of vertices of the border of a cluster, against the total amount of vertices. That is because it makes sense, intuitively, with my problem. But there is no mathematic foundation behind it.

My question is: **What are the most common methods to assess the quality of a clustering/partitioning ?**

Comment: Have you taken a look at recent papers and how they do it?

Comment: @dkaeae For graph partitioning, yes, since the problem definition gives also a mean to evaluate the quality of its solution (like minimizing the weight of the cut edges, or conductance ....). As for clustering, I did not find a good survey that describe several evaluation methods. I guess it's because there is a big variety of problems to solve, and approaches, under the name 'clustering algorithm'.

Comment: Searching a bit deeper, I found that this could be a duplicate of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6252/clustering-quality-measure), and that there are several relevant answers on [that link](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_we_say_that_a_clustering_quality_measure_is_good). It provides several measures already.